# Selenium,Django, On Ubuntu 20.04 digital ocean VPD

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, vps

I have created the web scraper and integrated it with Django. Everything is working perfectly fine. Now I want to host that Django app with webscraper on the VPS so that he can access it anywhere. I am using `gunicorn` and `nginx` too. I tried that Django app with `webdriver.remote()` using `seleniumgrid` its working fine on my normal windows environment, but as soon as I put it on my ubuntu vps it works only in half of cases - like  all my Django stuff is accessible and operational, but when my django calls the scraper, it just passes without any response.

```
def chromedriver_setup():
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
    # proxies = proxies = [{"_id":"62cd1bf852694154bb14f2e7","ip":"178.32.148.251","anonymityLevel":"elite","asn":"AS16276","city":"Gravelines","country":"FR","created_at":"2022-07-12T07:00:08.515Z","google":True,"isp":"OVH SAS","lastChecked":1657848951,"latency":5.13,"org":"MICHOTTE Maxime","port":"8080","protocols":["socks4"],  "speed":37,"updated_at":"2022-07-15T01:35:51.569Z"  },{"_id":"60d613cdce5b3bb0e932edce","ip":"64.227.62.123","port":"80","anonymityLevel":"elite","asn":"AS14061","city":"Santa Clara","country":"US","created_at":"2021-06-25T17:35:09.953Z","google":True,  "isp":"DigitalOcean, LLC","lastChecked":1657847332,"latency":153,"org":"DigitalOcean, LLC","protocols":["http"],  "speed":306,"updated_at":"2022-07-15T01:08:52.862Z"  ,"upTime":99.98473981382573,"upTimeSuccessCount":6552,"upTimeTryCount":6553}]
    # random_ip = random.choice(proxies)
    # PROXY = str(random_ip["ip"] + ":" + random_ip["port"])
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--headless")
    option.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

    option.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    # # option.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    print("chrome driver setup passed")
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='192.168.72.1:4444',
        desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        options=option,
    )
    return driver
```

Is there any way I can solve that issue or test i..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided information, I really cannot think of anything that would be causing the issue or anything that you should be looking for.

What I can suggest, however, considering the fact that your scraper is working fine on a windows environment is to find a windows server instead of Linux based machine and see how it goes there.